# scala.MatchError: <SomeStringvalue> (of class java.lang.String)

Tags: scala

I was getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: SomeStringValue (of class java.lang.String)
```

I found that it was causing because of "SomeStringValue" was not present in any of the cases:

```
val test = "SomeStringValue"
test match {
  case "Name" => println("Name")
  case "Age"  => println("Age")
  case "Sex"  => println("Sex")
}
```

When I added the else case: _ it ran correctly as below.

```
val test = "SomeStringValue"
test match {
  case "Name" => println("Name")
  case "Age"  => println("Age")
  case "Sex"  => println("Sex")
  case _      => println("Nothing Matched!!")
}
```

Question: What is the reason that there should always be a matching value in the case construct in Scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `match` construct is an expression in itself.

Suppose, instead of having `println` statements, you had integers, then the whole block would be a value of type `Integer`:

```
val test = "SomeStringValue"
val count: Int = test match {
  case "Name" => 1
  case "Age"  => 2
  case "Sex"  => 3
}
```

Now, what value should `count` be ? That's why the `match` statement must handle all possible cases.

In some cases (such as when pattern matching against a `sealed trait` or `sealed abstract class`), the compiler will be able to give you a warning, but most of the time, the error will be thrown at runtime, so you really need to be careful about it.

Comment: Can't it be null?

Comment: In this particular case, it cannot, since `Int`s are not objects. However, in more generality, if you agree to use constructs outside of functional programming, isn't it much more useful to have a specific `MatchError` exception, rather than a `null` which will give an undetermined `NullPointerException` later on? Another reason why it shouldn't be `null` (if you still need some), is that `null` is not an undertermined value, but an uninitialized value.